# Autolayout: Title View that Grows to Encompass UILabel + UIButton

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, uinavigationitem

I'm customizing the title view of my view controller so that displays (from left to right):

1. A UILabel that works pretty much like the default title label,
2. A UIButton of type info, placed right after the label at a fixed distance.

I expect that, as the label grows horizontally to accommodate longer text, it pushes the button farther to the right (the horizontal space between label and button remaining constant), while the whole title view resizes itself to contain label and button, while staying centred in the navigation bar.

**This is what I did (Interface Builder):**

1. Drag a UINavigationItem into the navigation bar;
2. Drag a UIView into the navigation item, to act as title view;
3. Drag label and button into title view, position and resize.
4. Setup the following constraints:

   Label -> Title View:

   1. Leading Space to Container Margin
   2. Center Vertically in Container

   Button -> Title View:

   1. Trailing Space to Container Margin
   2. Center Vertically in Container

(Title view itself is unconstrained)

However, the title view remains a fixed size. If at runtime I set a title longer than the placeholder set in the storyboard, it gets trimmed ("..."):

[image]

If instead I set a shorter one, additional space appears between the label and button:

[image]

**Alternatively**, if I add the following constraint:

Label -> Button:
   1. Horizontal Spacing

...now the button gets completely hidden by the label:

[image]

How can I have the title view grow horizontally (while remaining centred) just so that it fits both the (flexible) label and (fixed) button, and keeps the space between them fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigation item isn't setup to deal with this directly. You need to use your constraints to set the frame of the title view and then add it to the nab item. So, each time you change the text you need to do a little dance by removing the view, resizing it and then adding it again.  The key API is `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`.

Comment: I see... perhaps I'm better off designing my title view in  a separate xib (with its own constraints), and instantiate/configure/add to navigation item (i.e., set as `titleView`) at run time?

Comment: Yes, that is a clean approach

Answer (score 0):

Change constraint of button to horizontal space to label

Button -> Title View:

Horizontal Space to Label

Center Vertically in Container